# How many natural numbers less than $10^{2015}$ have their digits in non-decreasing order?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I am having pretty hard time with combinatorics.

Could someone explain me step-by-step how to get to solution?

**Note:** digits are observed from left to right.

Comment: Hint: such a number is completely characterized by giving the number of leading `1`s, then the number of following `2`s, and so forth.

Comment: @ZachBoyd This question is from two years earlier than that one.

Comment: Oops. Don't know I how I got the date confused. Deleting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's allow leading zeroes in the numbers, but require that they have exactly $2015$ digits ($10^{2015}$ is the smallest number with $2016$ digits).

Then, following user MJD's hint, we realize that the number of such numbers with digits in non-decreasing order is the same as the number of ways to put $2015$ balls into $10$ boxes (the number of balls in the first box representing the number of zeroes, etc.). We use [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), with $2015$ "stars" and $9$ "bars", to find that the total number of such numbers is $$\binom{2024}{9}-1$$

We subtract $1$ because zero is not a natural number.

<sup><sup><sup>at least, according to how I learned it - if you instead think that the natural numbers are the set of non-negative integers then you won't have to subtract $1$</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Those who think zero is natural will not have to subtract $1$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, I guess there is no consensus whether $\mathbb{N}$ refers to the set of positive integers or the set of non-negative integers.